# Rewriting if-else block in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I was given a piece of code by a colleague of mine which prevents a user from entering limited input in a textarea. The code works perfectly fine

```
var words = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;
if (words > 10) {
    var trimmed = $(this).val().split(/\s+/, 10).join(" ");
    $(this).val(trimmed + " ");
}
else {
    $('#word_left').text(10-words);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3qHwG/

I have read that jQuery can be written efficiently in a number of ways and I am wondering if this code can be rewritten without if-else or using a different approach?

Thanks for any help you can provide which will eventually increase my knowledge.

Comment: "The code works perfectly fine", everything is said. If ain't broke don't fix it

Comment: What's the harm in learning new ways to approach a problem?

Comment: @RC -- suit yourself. With your mentality libraries , frameworks, and applications would never strive to improve themselves or evolve.

Comment: Thanks for the support @MihaiStancu. I did post this question here with the belief that there are members in this forum who can help others increase their knowledge.

Comment: @Philtho Do you consider `abcd[tab]efgh` to be two words or one (here `tab` means `\t` character) or for that matter, all of space, tab, form feed, line feed to be word separators ?

Comment: @GaurangTandon I thought \s matches whitespace (spaces, tabs and new lines). No?

Comment: @Philtho So, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'd personally count the words using `(\b\w+\b)` instead of counting the spaces. And I'd block typing on keydown so the user doesn't see letters being written and then removed.

Comment: hmm..can you show me a demo?

Answer (score 1):

This extends readability:

```
$("#cnt").on('keyup', function (e) {
    var val = $(this).val(),
        // if val is empty, set trimmed to empty array, which translates to 'zero' length
        trimmed = val ? val.split(/\s+/, 10) : [];

    if (!((e.keyCode || window.event.keyCode) === 8)) // if not a backspace
        $(this).val(trimmed.join(" "));

    $("#word_left").text(10 - trimmed.length);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/3qHwG/7/)**

It performs exactly one operation of `.split` each time, which is better then yours, since yours performs not only one operation always, but also another operation if the limit of words exceeds.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Once I reach the last word, I have an issue using backspace in your code

Comment: One more issue. In your latest code, after you have reached 9 words and keep typing the last word never ends

Comment: @Philtho Version: http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/3qHwG/7/ . Sorry but I am not able to understand the problem you experience. Please clarify.

Comment: The last word never ends..whatever you type keeps getting appended to the 10th words making it never ending. Trying putting a space and type, it moves back a char and then appends the text

Comment: @Philtho Yes, i know. But you said, we don't have to allow words further than 10. Anyways, does [this help](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/3qHwG/8/) ?